# ¿Como hago para cerrar una ventana en PHP con un botón?

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero que al momento de presionar el botón "Cerrar Ventana", la ventana se cierre pero no logro que pase eso, lo hago con javascript normal y no tengo acción en nada no se que estoy haciendo mal, bueno tambien he leido que es dificil mezclar php con javascript y no se si eso sea el causante del problema que tengo ahora.

Este es mi código, ya hice todo solo que estoy trabado con este botón que aun no logro solucionar, ya he probado con varios metodos directos desde el input pero no me sale.
Este es mi código, ya hice todo solo que estoy trabado con este botón que aun no logro solucionar, ya he probado con varios metodos directos desde el input pero no me sale.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylos.css">
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Agregar un nuevo Registro Cliente</h1>
    <hr>
    <form class="formulario" action="registro.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="">Codigo del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="codigo" width="50px">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Nombre del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Apellido Paterno del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_paterno">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Apellido Materno del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_materno">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Edad del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="edad">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Estado Civil del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="estado_civil">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Fecha Nacimiento del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fecha_nacimiento">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Direccion del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="direccion">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Ciudad del cliente:</label>
            <input type="text" name="ciudad">
        </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
            <input type="button" value="cerrar" onclick="cerrar()" /> 
        </form>

        <form action="">
            <table id="tabla" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                        <th>Edad</th>
                        <th>Estado Civil</th>
                        <th>Fecha nacimiento</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>
                        <th>Ciudad</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($query as $row) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Codigo']; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Nombre']; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Ap_paterno']; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Ap_materno']; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Edad']; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Edo_civil']; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Fecha_nac']; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Direccion']; ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['Ciudad']; ?> </td>
                        <tr>
                    </tbody>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </form>

<script>
    function cerrar() {
        window.close();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

----REGISTRO.PHP----

```html
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidop = $_POST['apellido_paterno'];
$apellidom = $_POST['apellido_materno'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
$estado = $_POST['estado_civil'];
$nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO personal VALUES ('$codigo','$nombre','$apellidop','$apellidom','$edad','$estado','$nacimiento', '$direccion','$ciudad')";

$query = mysqli_query($conectar, $insertar); //

if($query){
    echo '<script> location.href= "index.php"; </script>';
} else {
    echo '<script> alert("Incorrecto"); location.href= "index.php"; </script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: No es que sea difícil mezclar JavaScript y PHP. Es que uno se ejecuta en un momento y viceversa. Te recomiendo que empieces a mirar cómo funciona el MVC, para separar lógica de presentacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los scripts de javascript sólo pueden cerrar las ventanas que anteriormente estos abrieron en el caso como el tuyo no es posible usarlos: Puedes ver porque en este link https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: Era eso, logre solucionarlo con un window.open al vacío.

Comment: Bien hecho, te deseo suerte en tu proyecto. :)

Comment: Gracias Lee se agradece :)

Comment: AlexisNarvaez,  como es que hiciste un window.open al vacio ? .  Saludos